# Xcode 6.3 can't find watchkit extension swift file

Tags: ios, xcode

We have a mixed code base in our WatchKit extension.  In a couple of Objective-C files, we need access to the Swift code base from the extension.  We've been using the following import:

```
#import "MyProject_WatchKit_Extension-Swift.h"
```

This has worked fine for the entire dev process.

I am in the process of moving to Xcode 6.3.  After updating our code base to Swift 1.2, I'm getting `File not found` for my extension-swift file.

What I've tried:

- Full clean w/ <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>
- Deleted derived data
- Deleted and reinstalled Xcode
- Changed extension module name and used that import
- Reverted to pre update commits and updated manually as opposed to the automated: `Convert > To Latest Swift>

Anybody have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer by editing the `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` field in the extension's build settings.  I had never previously edited this field, and I'm not sure how the value was removed.  I'll leave this here in case others have the same problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems Xcode has changed it's default behaviour for file paths defined in the target's build settings. Previously it was happy to look recursively for a file within the project directory, so you could just define the file name and you were good to go. Now you need to prepend the folder name.

Go to your targets build settings and search for 'Objective-C Bridging Header', you'll probably see the entry 'MyProject_WatchKit_Extension-Swift.h'. You need to prepend the path to the file relative to the root project folder.

If your folder was structured as so:

```
 PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER
 - CLASSES_FOLDER
 -- MyProject_WatchKit_Extension-Swift.h
 - .xcodeproj
 - TESTS_FOLDER
```

Then you would need to change the value to

`CLASSES_FOLDER/MyProject_WatchKit_Extension-Swift.h`

Comment: It's not in Objective-C Bridging Header, that's the other direction :).  Have you tried this?  The swift header is generated by xcode and defining a folder for the import wouldn't be really feasible since we don't know or have control over where Xcode puts it (as far as I know).  I was able to solve it by declaring the interface header explicitly.

Comment: This solved my problem. If you have a obj c header files in your main iPhone app and if you are accessing this inside your watch kit extension, follow below steps.
1. Add obj c-bridging header in your watch kit extension project.
2. Add required header files in main project to your bring header